# Solidity dynamic array order & index

Tags: solidity

Just a question around dynamic solidity arrays. Is the order always guaranteed? I.e.

```
string[] public myArray2 = ['value0', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
```

Will myArray2[1] always contain 'value1' for the lifespan of the contract?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, myArray2[1] will always contain the value 'value1' for the lifespan of the contract, unless it is explicitly modified by a contract function or by an external account with the appropriate permissions.